# Java BigInteger implementation

Tags: java, beginner, integer

I've written a java application that can handle operations on big integers implemented with array list of digits.

I have a difficulty with the way I implemented the divide method, because when the difference between the two numbers is high, the operation can take a huge amount of time.

I'd like to hear your thoughts about this implementation and ways it can be improved. Here is the class and its test class:

**BigInt.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BigInt implements Comparable<BigInt> {

    private static final char MINUS_CHAR = '-';
    private static final char PLUS_CHAR = '+';

    // Saves the digits of the number - last element represents the smallest unit of the number
    private ArrayList<Integer> numberDigits = new ArrayList<>();

    // Indication if the number is negative
    private boolean negative;

    // String representation as given by the user
    private String stringNumber;

    BigInt(String number){

        if (number.equals("")){
            stringNumber = "0";
            numberDigits.add(0);
        }
        else {
            // Dealing with the positive/negative signs
            char firstChar = number.charAt(0);
            if (firstChar == MINUS_CHAR || firstChar == PLUS_CHAR) {
                if (firstChar == MINUS_CHAR)
                    negative = true;

                number = number.substring(1);
            }

            // Regex to remove zeros at the beginning of the number
            number = number.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
            stringNumber = number;

            // Saving the digits
            for (int index = 0; index < number.length(); index++) {
                int curDigNumericVal = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(index));

                // Current char is not a valid digit
                if (curDigNumericVal == -1)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();

                numberDigits.add(curDigNumericVal);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isNegative() {
        return negative;
    }

    private void flipNegativity() {
        if (stringNumber == "0")
            return;

        negative = !negative;
        if (stringNumber.charAt(0) == MINUS_CHAR){
            stringNumber = stringNumber.substring(1);
        } else {
            stringNumber = MINUS_CHAR + stringNumber;
        }
    }

    // Adding another bigInt number to the current bigInt number
    BigInt plus(BigInt otherNumber) {

        // current is negative, other is positive - subtract current from the other
        if (negative && !otherNumber.isNegative()) {
            return otherNumber.minus(new BigInt(stringNumber));
        }

        // other is negative - subtract its value
        if (otherNumber.isNegative()) {
            return minus(new BigInt(otherNumber.toString()));
        }

        // Setting the longer number of the two numbers
        ArrayList<Integer> longerNumber, shorterNumber;
        if (numberDigits.size() >= otherNumber.numberDigits.size()) {
            longerNumber = numberDigits;
            shorterNumber = otherNumber.numberDigits;
        }
        else {
            longerNumber = otherNumber.numberDigits;
            shorterNumber = numberDigits;
        }

        int lengthsDifferences = longerNumber.size() - shorterNumber.size();


        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();

        // Initializing a carry for every addition
        int carry = 0;


        // Iterating from smallest unit digit to the biggest
        for (int index = shorterNumber.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            int shorterNumberDigit = shorterNumber.get(index);
            int longerNumberDigit = longerNumber.get(index + lengthsDifferences);

            int newDigit = shorterNumberDigit + longerNumberDigit + carry;

            // Calculating the carry and the new digit
            carry = newDigit / 10;
            newDigit = newDigit % 10;

            resultString.append(newDigit);
        }

        // Adding digits of longer number
        for (int index = lengthsDifferences - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            int currDig = longerNumber.get(index);

            // Check if need to add carry
            if (currDig + carry == 10) {
                resultString.append(0);
                carry = 1;
            } else {
                resultString.append(currDig + carry);
                carry = 0;
            }
        }

        // Check if there is carry on last digit
        if (carry > 0)
            resultString.append(carry);

        return new BigInt(resultString.reverse().toString());
    }

    BigInt minus(BigInt otherNumber){

        // If the other number is negative, add its value
        if (otherNumber.isNegative()) {
            return plus(new BigInt(otherNumber.stringNumber));
        }

        // subtract a bigger number than the current
        if (this.compareTo(otherNumber) < 0) {
            BigInt result = otherNumber.minus(this);
            result.flipNegativity();
            return result;
        }

        // Other number is positive and not greater than current:
        int lengthsDifferences = numberDigits.size() - otherNumber.numberDigits.size();

        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();

        int carry = 0;

        for (int index = otherNumber.numberDigits.size() - 1; index >=0 ; index--) {
            int biggerNumDig = numberDigits.get(index + lengthsDifferences) - carry;
            int smallerNumDig = otherNumber.numberDigits.get(index);

            carry = 0;

            if (biggerNumDig < smallerNumDig){
                carry = 1;
                biggerNumDig += 10;
            }

            resultString.append(biggerNumDig - smallerNumDig);
        }

        for (int index = lengthsDifferences - 1; index >=0 ; index--) {
            int currDig = numberDigits.get(index);

            // Check if carry is needed
            if (carry > currDig){
                resultString.append(currDig + 10 - carry);
                carry = 1;
            } else {
                resultString.append(currDig - carry);
                carry = 0;
            }
        }

        return new BigInt(resultString.reverse().toString());
    }

    // Multiply bigInt
    BigInt multiply(BigInt otherNumber){

        BigInt finalResult = new BigInt("0");
        BigInt currentUnit = new BigInt("1");

        for (int otherNumIndex = otherNumber.numberDigits.size() - 1; otherNumIndex >=0; otherNumIndex--){
            int currentOtherNumDigit = otherNumber.numberDigits.get(otherNumIndex);

            // Holds the result of multiplication of the number by the current digit of the other number

            BigInt currentResult = new BigInt("0");
            BigInt currentDigitUnit = new BigInt(currentUnit.toString());

            for (int index = numberDigits.size() - 1; index >=0; index--) {
                int currentDigit = numberDigits.get(index);
                int digitsMultiplication = currentDigit * currentOtherNumDigit;

                currentResult = currentDigitUnit.MultiplyUnit(digitsMultiplication);
                currentDigitUnit.multiplyByTen();
            }

            currentUnit.multiplyByTen();
            finalResult = finalResult.plus(currentResult);
        }

        // Check if need to flip negativity
        if (otherNumber.isNegative() && !isNegative() || isNegative() && !otherNumber.isNegative())
            finalResult.flipNegativity();

        return finalResult;
    }

    BigInt divide(BigInt otherNumber) {

        if (isBigIntZero(otherNumber))
            throw new ArithmeticException();

        // Handling the case where the current number is positive and the other is negative
        if (otherNumber.isNegative() && !isNegative()) {
            BigInt result = divide(new BigInt(otherNumber.stringNumber));
            result.flipNegativity();
            return result;

            // Handling the case where the current number is negative and the other is positive
        } else if (!otherNumber.isNegative() && isNegative()) {
            BigInt result = new BigInt(stringNumber).divide(otherNumber);
            result.flipNegativity();
            return result;
        }

        int compareResult = this.compareTo(otherNumber);
        if (compareResult == 0)
            return new BigInt("1");
        else if (compareResult < 0)
            return new BigInt("0");

        BigInt result = new BigInt("0");
        BigInt tempNumber = new BigInt("0");

        while (tempNumber.compareTo(this) < 0) {
            tempNumber = tempNumber.plus(otherNumber);
            result = result.plus(new BigInt("1"));
        }

        return result;

    }

    private boolean isBigIntZero(BigInt number) {
        return number.stringNumber.replace("0", "").equals("");

    }

    // Multiply a unit of BigInt with an integer. Example: 1000000000000000000 * 54
    private BigInt MultiplyUnit(int majorUnits){

        // Setting the string representation
        String majorUnitsString = String.valueOf(majorUnits);
        String newNumber = majorUnitsString + stringNumber.substring(1);

        return new BigInt(newNumber);
    }

    private void multiplyByTen() {
        this.numberDigits.add(0);
        stringNumber += '0';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BigInt other) {

        // Current is negative, other is positive
        if (isNegative() && !other.isNegative())
             return -1;

        // Current is positive, other is negative
        else if (!isNegative() && other.isNegative()){
            return 1;
        }

        // Both are negative
        else if (isNegative()){
            // Current is negative and has more digits - therefore it is smaller
            if (numberDigits.size() > other.numberDigits.size())
                return -1;
            // Current is negative and has less digits - Therefore it is bigger
            else if (numberDigits.size() < other.numberDigits.size())
                return 1;

            // Both have same number of digits - need to iterate them
            else
                for (int index = 0; index < numberDigits.size(); index++) {

                    // Current has bigger negative digit - therefore it is smaller
                    if (numberDigits.get(index) > other.numberDigits.get(index))
                        return -1;

                    // Current has smaller negative digit - therefore it is smaller
                    else if (numberDigits.get(index) < other.numberDigits.get(index))
                            return 1;
                }

                // If we have reached here, the numbers are completely identical
                return 0;
        }

        // If we have reached here, both numbers are positive

        // Current is positive and has more digits - Therefore it is bigger
        if (numberDigits.size() > other.numberDigits.size()) {
            return 1;
        }

        // Current is positive and has less digits - Therefore it is smaller
        else if (numberDigits.size() < other.numberDigits.size())
            return -1;

            // Both have same number of digits - need to iterate them
        else
            for (int index = 0; index < numberDigits.size(); index++) {

                // Current has bigger positive digit - therefore it is bigger
                if (numberDigits.get(index) > other.numberDigits.get(index))
                    return 1;

                    // Current has smaller positive digit - therefore it is smaller
                else if (numberDigits.get(index) < other.numberDigits.get(index))
                    return -1;
            }

        // If we have reached here, the numbers are completely identical
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // self check
        if (this == o)
            return true;

        // null check
        if (o == null)
            return false;

        // type check and cast
        if (getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        BigInt other = (BigInt) o;
        // field comparison

        return other.toString().equals(stringNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return stringNumber;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
import com.sun.javaws.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInt firstNumber;
        BigInt secondNumber;

        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        firstNumber = inputBigIntNumber();

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        secondNumber = inputBigIntNumber();

        System.out.println("The result of plus is: " + firstNumber.plus(secondNumber));
        System.out.println("The result of minus is: " + firstNumber.minus(secondNumber));
        System.out.println("The result of multiply is: " + firstNumber.multiply(secondNumber));

        try {
            System.out.println("The result of divide is: " + firstNumber.divide(secondNumber));
        } catch (ArithmeticException ex){
            System.out.println("Can not divide by zero");
        }

    }

    // Taking a valid integer input from the user (greater than 0)
    private static BigInt inputBigIntNumber(){

        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        while (true) {
            try {
                return new BigInt(str);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid number, please try again: ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Main

> ```
> import com.sun.javaws.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException;
> ```

Are you using Eclipse? This looks like an IDE being unhelpful. The `InvalidArgumentException` you want is in `java.lang`.

---

> ```
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         BigInt firstNumber;
>         BigInt secondNumber;
>
>         System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
>         firstNumber = inputBigIntNumber();
>
>         System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
>         secondNumber = inputBigIntNumber();
>
>         System.out.println("The result of plus is: " + firstNumber.plus(secondNumber));
>         System.out.println("The result of minus is: " + firstNumber.minus(secondNumber));
>         System.out.println("The result of multiply is: " + firstNumber.multiply(secondNumber));
>
>         try {
>             System.out.println("The result of divide is: " + firstNumber.divide(secondNumber));
>         } catch (ArithmeticException ex){
>             System.out.println("Can not divide by zero");
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

This isn't a great way of doing tests. Much better to have unit tests.

I tested it with input `17` `42` and the value given for the multiplication is `420`, which is clearly wrong.

---

### BigInt

> ```
>     // Saves the digits of the number - last element represents the smallest unit of the number
>     private ArrayList<Integer> numberDigits = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

Thumbs up for documenting the endianness clearly. In my experience the opposite endianness is easier to work with.

I think `BigInt` is immutable, so I'm not sure what advantage there is to using `ArrayList<Integer>` over `int[]`, and the boxing/unboxing is an obvious disadvantage.

---

> ```
>     // Indication if the number is negative
>     private boolean negative;
> ```

I would call it `isNegative` as a hint that it's a Boolean and to read well in `if` statements.

---

> ```
>     // String representation as given by the user
>     private String stringNumber;
> ```

I'm curious as to why the class keeps two copies of the digits. Is that a time/memory tradeoff due to `toString()` being a bottleneck?

---

> ```
>     private boolean isNegative() {
>         return negative;
>     }
> ```

Why is this `private`? It might be useful if it were `public`, but for private use you have access to the field.

---

> ```
>     private void flipNegativity() {
>         if (stringNumber == "0")
>             return;
>
>         negative = !negative;
> ```

Ah, it's not immutable. Some explicit documentation of this at the top of the class would be nice.

---

> ```
>     // Adding another bigInt number to the current bigInt number
>     BigInt plus(BigInt otherNumber) {
> ```

> ```
>     BigInt minus(BigInt otherNumber){
> ```

> ```
>     // Multiply bigInt
>     BigInt multiply(BigInt otherNumber){
> ```

Again, not public?

---

> ```
>         BigInt finalResult = new BigInt("0");
>         BigInt currentUnit = new BigInt("1");
>
>         for (int otherNumIndex = otherNumber.numberDigits.size() - 1; otherNumIndex >=0; otherNumIndex--){
>             int currentOtherNumDigit = otherNumber.numberDigits.get(otherNumIndex);
>
>             // Holds the result of multiplication of the number by the current digit of the other number
>
>             BigInt currentResult = new BigInt("0");
>             BigInt currentDigitUnit = new BigInt(currentUnit.toString());
>
>             for (int index = numberDigits.size() - 1; index >=0; index--) {
>                 int currentDigit = numberDigits.get(index);
>                 int digitsMultiplication = currentDigit * currentOtherNumDigit;
>
>                 currentResult = currentDigitUnit.MultiplyUnit(digitsMultiplication);
>                 currentDigitUnit.multiplyByTen();
>             }
>
>             currentUnit.multiplyByTen();
>             finalResult = finalResult.plus(currentResult);
>         }
> ```

Maybe you could factor out the addition into a method which takes two input `BigInt`s or representations thereof and a power of 10 offset for the second. Then you could share the code with `add` and reuse it here, saving all the `multiplyByTen()` etc.

Sketch code:

```
int[] accumulator = new int[worst case length of the output];
for (int powerOfTen = 0; powerOfTen < numberDigits.size(); powerOfTen++) {
    addImpl(accumulator, powerOfTen, numberDigits.get(powerOfTen), otherNumber.numberDigits);
}
```

The core of `add(BigInt)` would be

```
accumulator = new int[worst case length of the output]
addImpl(accumulator, 0, 1, numberDigits);
addImpl(accumulator, 0, 1, otherNumber.numberDigits);
```

---

> ```
>     BigInt divide(BigInt otherNumber) {
> ```

This could use a comment about rounding. It looks like it rounds to zero: is that correct?

> ```
>         // Handling the case where the current number is positive and the other is negative
>         if (otherNumber.isNegative() && !isNegative()) {
>             BigInt result = divide(new BigInt(otherNumber.stringNumber));
>             result.flipNegativity();
>             return result;
>
>             // Handling the case where the current number is negative and the other is positive
>         } else if (!otherNumber.isNegative() && isNegative()) {
>             BigInt result = new BigInt(stringNumber).divide(otherNumber);
>             result.flipNegativity();
>             return result;
>         }
>
>         int compareResult = this.compareTo(otherNumber);
>         if (compareResult == 0)
>             return new BigInt("1");
>         else if (compareResult < 0)
>             return new BigInt("0");
> ```

That doesn't look right. If both numbers are negative and `this.compareTo(otherNumber) < 0` then the result should be at least `1`.

> ```
>         BigInt result = new BigInt("0");
>         BigInt tempNumber = new BigInt("0");
>
>         while (tempNumber.compareTo(this) < 0) {
>             tempNumber = tempNumber.plus(otherNumber);
>             result = result.plus(new BigInt("1"));
>         }
> ```

The keywords you need to search for are *long division*. That's the algorithm they teach you in school which everyone forgets by the time they leave school.

---

> ```
>     @Override
>     public int compareTo(BigInt other) {
>
>         // Current is negative, other is positive
>         if (isNegative() && !other.isNegative())
>              return -1;
>
>         // Current is positive, other is negative
>         else if (!isNegative() && other.isNegative()){
>             return 1;
>         }
> ```

Might be good to add an equality test before anything else: at the very least `if (this == other) return 0`. Other than that, so far, so good; but then it goes off the rails. It might be a lot simpler to look at the sign of `this.minus(other)`.

---

> ```
>     @Override
>     public boolean equals(Object o) {
>         // self check
>         if (this == o)
>             return true;
>
>         // null check
>         if (o == null)
>             return false;
>
>         // type check and cast
>         if (getClass() != o.getClass())
>             return false;
>
>         BigInt other = (BigInt) o;
>         // field comparison
>
>         return other.toString().equals(stringNumber);
>     }
> ```

If you override `equals` you should also override `getHashCode()` to ensure that the class works correctly with `HashSet`, `HashMap`, etc.

Comment: thanks for the useful comments. Could you further explain this statement: `Maybe you could factor out the addition into a method which takes two input BigInts or representations thereof and a power of 10 offset for the second. Then you could share the code with add and reuse it here, saving all the multiplyByTen() etc`. And moreover, regarding your suggestion using the `minus` method in the compareTo - I would really like to do that but the `minus` method uses the `CompareTo` and the `plus` uses the `minus` so it can't be used as well. Do you have another suggestion to solve that?

Comment: I've added some outline code which I hope will make that clearer. Fair point on the circular reference between `minus` and `compareTo`. My own big integer class just does addition and multiplication because it's for combinatoric problems where the bottleneck in Java's built-in `BigInteger` is `toString()`, but I think that maybe the solution would be to do the addition using tens complement: that way it's just an addition and a bit of bookkeeping at the end if the result turns out to be negative.

Comment: Instead of `InvalidArgumentException` (which comes from .NET), Java code typically uses `IllegalArgumentException`.